# Windows XP INSTALL BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-installation

Recently I got a virus on my computer that completely wiped the hdd. I am trying to install windows xp to this: DV7-636bus laptop from HP, and I get the following BSOD:

```
A problem...............and Then Select Safe Mode.

Technical Information:

***STOP: 0x0000007E (0xC0000005,0xF73B9D66,0xF78D1EA0,0xF78D1B9C)

acpi.sys - Address F72B9D66 base at F73AE000, Datestamp 480252b1
```

Does any one know of a solution for this?

Comment: Does it BSOD while installing or after?

Comment: while. After it loads the drivers, it says: Windows is loading setup, then I get the BSOD.

Comment: mic84 answered my question though. Thank you.